# What potential things can be found for each Signal Scanner selection?

Tags: no-mans-sky

When you get to a scanner you are given 4 things to scan for:

1. Monolith
2. Outpost(?)
3. Transmission
4. Shelter

I think Monolith is obviously going to be alien artifacts almost every time but the other 3 all kind of overlap. What landmarks does each give?

Answer (score 8):

Monolith - is either going to be a monolith or a ruin.

Outpost - is either going to be an outpost with an alien resident, or an "Ops Centre" (haven't investigated these too closely as they're locked) or manufacturing facility (which seems to give crafting blueprints after you break in). I think it might also include sites where you can find a trade network computer.

Transmission - a beacon which then finds another location on the same world, or an observatory which can find a location on another world. It could be a broken ship which you can repair and reclaim.

Shelter - either a "shelter" (an abandoned camp with some resources), or a drop-pod.

Comment: For me Transmission quite often shows me a crashed ship

Comment: Outposts for me are usually manufacturing facilities.

Comment: Cool - haven't had a ship yet